# BackgroundTransfer inside BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, background-task, background-transfer

In my application i need to synchonize some data on a TimeTriggered intervall. Now i have built a BackgroundTask with TimeTrigger, inside this task i im running a BackgroundTransfer operation. This works, but i havesome questions about that.

1. Is this a good solution, orare there better ones for this scenario?
2. There are some mysterious execution things. If i deploy the app as debug version to my phone, everything works like a charm, all Transfer operations are completed within one execution of the BackgroundTask, this takes +/- 15 minutes. Now if i deploy the app as release version to my phone, the BackgroundTask transfers data only for 1-2 minutes and stops, till the next execution from the TimeTrigger is fired. Why is there a difference or why is this?

**edit:**
Resource intensive Task is not an option for me, the app is built on WinRT store app. When this is a limitation from backgroundTask, how then can i perform such an operation from the background?

**edit2:**
@kiewic, im calling it awaitable, will change that, but what is then the difference, as this is executet in the background task?

Comment: 15 minutes of download? I think that backgroundtask is not designed for a such nuge job. Try resource intensitive task, but there also some limitations.

Comment: The OS imposes networking and power caps.

Comment: Can you post the code of how are you calling StartAsync()? Make sure you are not awaiting this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the BackgroundTask and the BackgroundTransfer.  These are two different things.

The job of your background task is to **start** your background transfers. The job of your BackgroundTransfer (upload or download operation) is to **perform the transfer independently of your application**.

The transfer doesn't need to take place within the BackgroundTask.  If you call *await* on the start of the background transfer, you will wait until the upload is complete.  If you don't, you will continue executing within your task (e.g. if you are in a loop, you can begin to build and start the next upload).

Once you have started a background transfer, it is managed independently of your app or any task by the OS.  It can even survive the phone being restarted.

Comment: That helped me a lot, thank you very much! Now i understand the way how to use a background task.